# How to calculate the Haversine formula in CLIPS

Tags: clips

I'm trying to calculate de distance between to city using `latitude` and `longitude`. For this reason, I'm trying to use the haversine formula in CLIPS but I'm not able to calculate the `arctan2` (2-argument arctangent). Is there any way to solve this issue?

This is the code that I'm trying to reproduce:

```
Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
   return this * Math.PI / 180;
}

var lat2 = 42.741; 
var lon2 = -71.3161; 
var lat1 = 42.806911; 
var lon1 = -71.290611; 

var R = 6371; // km 
//has a problem with the .toRad() method below.
var x1 = lat2-lat1;
var dLat = x1.toRad();  
var x2 = lon2-lon1;
var dLon = x2.toRad();  
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
                Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c; 

alert(d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a deffunction that implements atan2 in terms of atan.

[image: Computation of atan2]

Comment: Ok thank you, I was wondering if there was another solution that I was missing but yes, this can solve the issue!

Comment: The other solution is to create a user-defined function as described in the Advanced Programming Guide and recompile CLIPS. There's a bunch of examples in the CLIPS source file emathfun.c for the existing functions such as cos, sin, tan, etc. The initial set of math functions were written back in the late 1980s so this one may have been overlooked or not part of the C standard at that point.